# annotation based mapping with spring is not working. 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I always get "requested resource is not available" from tomcat, when trying to access my pages with annotation based controllers.

Controller:

```
 @Controller
 public class HelloWorldController {

     @RequestMapping("/hello")
     public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

I try to access /hello.htm and get the 404. mainpage.htm works fine, but its controller is not the annotated type.

dipsatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">    
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/blog.properties"/>  


<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycomp.controller" />

<!--ViewResolver määrab kontrollerklassist tagastatud parameetri järgi vaate. Hetkel jsp lehekülg -->
<bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean name="/mainpage.htm" class="com.mycomp.controller.MainPage">
    <property name="message" value="${message}"/>
    <property name="maxposts" value="${maxposts}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you have the DispatcherServlet setup in the web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to specify the request method and also point out the names of variables in annotation (also 1st slash is not mandatory):

```
@RequestMapping(value="hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: oh god, eclipse was refusing to rebuild it for all this time and i didn't notice it. I had it right like 5 hours ago T_T.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the corresponding view to your jsp folder? Since you are using the [ModelAndView(Object view, String modelName, Object modelObject)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) constructor, I would expect to see a *hello.jsp* implementation (that possibly uses the `message` model object).

Comment: yeah i have<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>